# Get data from xml response in Jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter

```
                 Hi Everyone!
```

I would like to get status from this response from Jmeter.How can i create regexp for that? 
             I just want to get 'vacant' from response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns5:GetRandomMSISDNListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.trump.com/products/common/core" xmlns:ns3="http://www.trump.com/products/common/rr" xmlns:ns4="http://www.yota224.com/vux/domains/common/core" xmlns:ns5="http://www.yota224.com/vux/services/inventory">
      <ns2:extension>
        <ns2:item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:RequestContextType">
          <ns2:correlationId>8f7ce7e1-31ae-40fe-82ba-4d59f634e599</ns2:correlationId>
        </ns2:item>
      </ns2:extension>
      <msisdnList>
        <homeRegion>1078</homeRegion>
        <msisdn>9992146221</msisdn>
        <status>vacant</status>
      </msisdnList>
    </ns5:GetRandomMSISDNListResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you targeting to do it via Regular Expressions - the relevant one would be something like:

```
<status>(\w+)</status>
```

Here is how it looks in the "RegExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image: View Results Tree]

---

Also it might be easier to use [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) which is designed for working with XML data. In that case the relevant XPath query to get the status will be as simple as:

```
//status
```

[image: XPath Extractor Demo]